# The "pip install pgmpy" statement for Python in Jupyter Notebook does not work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pgmpy

When I try to install "pgmpy" in the Jupyter notebook using the statement "pip install pgmpy", the notebook stays in a "busy" state, with the hourglass icon staying there for a very long time. Every time I try to install it, it has been loading for at least an hour or two, which is unprecedented for my Jupyter notebook. Simply put, nothing is happening. This is also the case for the statement "!pip install pgmpy", with an exclamation mark to run as a shell command. Is there anything else I would need to install before focusing on pgmpy? Should anything else be done?

I would truly appreciate any help in this matter. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're doing everything right. I would suggest trying the same command inside a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using **conda install -c ankurankan pgmpy**, as suggested in https://pypi.org/project/pgmpy/?

Also, I would suggest to run your code in Google collab. **!pip install pgmpy** should work there.

Comment: Your suggestion to run the statement in Google Collab worked. Thank you very much!